# Experience with PHP QuickHash for large arrays

Tags: php, arrays, performance, memory

Does anyone have any experience with PHP QuickHash (http://php.net/manual/en/book.quickhash.php)?

Some early testing shows massive improvements in memory usage for large arrays. An array with 1M items takes 226mb with a normal array and only 41mb with QuickHash and speed is about the same.

However I can hardly find stories from people actually using it in production environment so I'm curious to see if there are any reasons for not using it in production.

Comment: It seems to me, that you can save only following key=>value pairs: INT=>INT, INT=>STRING, STRING=>INT. What about multi dimensional arrays?

Comment: Definitely looks promising :) what would stop me is the fact that the package is still in beta.

Comment: @rabudde: For this project these pairs are all I need. Multi dimensional isn't possible but also not needed for me.

Comment: @Jack: Indeed, thats why I asked ;)

Comment: @raina77ow The technical problem to solve is how to store large amounts of items in an array without massive memory usage. I have already given a possible answer but I wasn't sure if that is the way to go or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been updated to version 1.0 stable and is, according to the developer, already several years in production and is working good.

We use it now in a project and it works great. It has a much better memory usage than the default arrays. One minor issue (for us) is that it only works with int32 and not int64, however we have been able to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

It is for low memory consumption and fast serialization and deserialization  , from your posting I can understand that low memory consumption is achieved , you have to understand what is actually meant by serialization of datastructures and it varies architectures and implementations . I have never used it but I had tested this .